# Configure webpack for Nodejs so that you can run the app using the absolute path

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a Nodejs project for which I want to create an executable, but I also want to use it as a module that I can import in other projects.

I'm using Webpack to bundle everything and create the executable and it works well IF i'm running the script from the project directory. If I try to run the script from another path, then I get a ENOENT: no such file or directory error.

My project structure:

```
project_root
     |
     |-- lib
          |-- dependent_library.js
          |-- dependent_library_2.js
     |-- index.js
     |-- cli.js
     |-- some_script.sh
     |-- webpack.config.js
```

My webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
   entry: './cli.js',
   target: 'node',
   node: {
      __dirname: true
   },
   output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'my_executable'
   },
   plugins: [
      new webpack.BannerPlugin({
         banner: '#!/usr/bin/env node\n',
         raw: true
      })
   ]
}
```

I have a `fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../some_script.sh')` in my `dependent_library.js` file. This file is imported in the `cli.js` file, which is the entry point for webpack. I run webpack, it bundles my executable, all is good.

**The problem** arises when I want to run the executable from `../project_root` or some other path in the system, which is something that I would obviously like to do.

> e.g. My project is in `/home/my_user/workspace/project_root/`. I cd to
>   `/home/my_user/workspace/` and run `project_root/my_executable`

This is where I get the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'lib/../some_script.sh'
```

My sure there's a way to configure Webpack for this scenario to work, but I haven't figured out how yet. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Does your wepback config have -> `target: 'node',node: {  __dirname: false, __filename: false, }`

Comment: @Keith I've tried that, but then the executable won't run even in the project root, because it's trying to find `some_script.sh` in `project_root/../some_script.sh` instead of `project_root/lib/../some_script.sh`. And if I modify my fs.readFileSync to `fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/some_script.sh')`, then using my project as a module won't work because my `dependent_library.js` file has it's __dirname in `project_root/lib` and won't be able to find `some_script.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a combination of @Keith's answer with some code change

I've set:

```
node: {
   __dirname: false
}
```

And I've also changed the `dependent_library.js` to check wether the script exists in the current directory or not. So if `__dirname + /some_script.sh` exists, then it will just read it - and this is what happens when you run the executable. The difference is that with the webpack node.__dirname option set to false, the __dirname returns the absolute path to the executable.

If `__dirname + /some_script.sh` doesn't exist, then it tries to read `__dirname + /../some_script.sh` - we assume the project is imported as a module. Because the library where this code runs is in project_root/lib, we need to go back one level.